# Setting up random sample times in R

Tags: r

I'm creating simulation data using R for NONMEM.

I want to know how to create random sets of 3 sample times for a population of 34.

Here is my code:

```
nsubjects <- 34

times <- rep((c(runif(1, 0.5, 1), runif(1, 12, 48), runif(1, 47, 49))), nsubjects)
```

Now, the only problem is that this set of triplets have no interindividual variability. In the real world not every sample is taken at the exact same time for everyone, that's why I used the runif command to set the conditions. The first sample must be taken between 0.5-1 hours, the second between 12-48 hours, and the third sample between 47-49 hours.

I don't care if this data is in an array, they just need to be situated in one vector (so no matrix, I don't want three sampling time columns because I'm attaching the data to ID's.

Each set of 3 must be within the parameters of their intended runif (min-max values), there should be 3 * 34 samples, each with their own intended randomized values.

Comment: I think you need `times <- replicate( nsubjects, c(runif(1, 0.5, 1), runif(1, 12, 48), runif(1, 47, 49)))`

Comment: A for loop is also doing the trick `nsubjects <- 34

for(i in 1:nsubjects ){assign(paste0("c",i),c(runif(1, 0.5, 1), runif(1, 12, 48), runif(1, 47, 49)))}`

Comment: `t`ranspose @Ric's solution and make a `data.frame`, `df1 |> data.frame(t(replicate(nrow(df1), c(runif(1, 0.5, 1), runif(1, 12, 48), runif(1, 47, 49)))))`

Answer (score 1):

R's pseudo-RNG's are vectorized, define lower and upper limits and one call to `runif` will do the job.
In the code below I compare the vectorized results with the results in [Ric's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75946838/setting-up-random-sample-times-in-r#comment133954433_75946838).

```r
nsubjects <- 34L

set.seed(2023)    # make the results reproducible
times1 <- replicate(nsubjects, c(runif(1, 0.5, 1), runif(1, 12, 48), runif(1, 47, 49)))

set.seed(2023)    # reproduce the results above
lo <- c(0.5, 12, 47)
hi <- c(1, 48, 49)
times2 <- replicate(nsubjects, runif(3, lo, hi))

all(times1 == times2)
#> [1] TRUE

identical(times1, times2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can also substitute `length(lo)` (or `hi`) for the constant `3` in the call to `runif`:

```
times2 <- replicate(nsubjects, runif(length(lo), lo, hi))
```

And since you want a vector, not a matrix, given that R's matrices are column-first order, just coerce the result above to vector with `c()`

```
times2 <- c(times2)
```

or directly

```
times <- c(replicate(nsubjects, runif(3, lo, hi)))
```

The complete code is

```r
nsubjects <- 34L

set.seed(2023)    # make the results reproducible
lo <- c(0.5, 12, 47)
hi <- c(1, 48, 49)
times2 <- c(replicate(nsubjects, runif(length(lo), lo, hi)))
times2
#>   [1]  0.7333070 24.0668743 47.3256351  0.6980600 13.0941023 47.2417697
#>   [7]  0.7130828 34.2428837 47.5264165  0.7381619 43.0434840 47.2977573
#>  [13]  0.5902150 47.9738392 48.6834824  0.5713245 24.4145419 48.7792509
#>  [19]  0.6599241 37.5245700 48.2563034  0.7190863 24.2362570 48.8661852
#>  [25]  0.8564772 34.7106674 48.4928989  0.5557251 21.8383865 47.1970362
#>  [31]  0.8787647 35.8893157 48.4487222  0.7294733 36.2783489 48.4010272
#>  [37]  0.9075361 36.8825336 48.4328247  0.9452899 24.2506878 48.3371257
#>  [43]  0.6921270 20.4640812 48.7769941  0.9007258 33.4713985 48.9540355
#>  [49]  0.6640525 40.9864810 47.0646308  0.7241449 21.5303418 47.8185350
#>  [55]  0.5972984 31.5655505 48.8702074  0.8870188 47.8877970 48.6452517
#>  [61]  0.6958527 25.8689813 48.7982756  0.6594265 19.5127854 48.1283543
#>  [67]  0.7410422 14.3441268 47.5225547  0.6651678 23.9003085 47.1847066
#>  [73]  0.8469968 16.1936265 48.7411946  0.5643353 42.0736070 47.4753838
#>  [79]  0.7252093 42.0347502 48.3315939  0.7720596 35.8425095 48.7470245
#>  [85]  0.8341940 19.6876291 47.8381487  0.7313880 34.2771132 47.9674524
#>  [91]  0.8781355 19.9780284 48.9823589  0.9898648 42.9250703 47.4830284
#>  [97]  0.8156663 38.7856431 48.5488074  0.8374183 38.8840239 48.9481844
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Here is a solution that avoids `merge`. Create a temp column `count` with the number of ID repeats needed. `uncount` the data by that column. Run the `c(replicate(etc))` code above to create the new column.
The result at the end shows numbers in the specified ranges.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

nsubjects <- 34L
df1 <- data.frame(ID = seq.int(nsubjects))

lo <- c(0.5, 12, 47)
hi <- c(1, 48, 49)

set.seed(2023)    # make the results reproducible
df1 %>%
  mutate(count = length(lo)) %>%
  uncount(count) %>%
  mutate(TIME = c(replicate(nsubjects, runif(length(lo), lo, hi)))) -> df2

head(df2, n = 10)
#>    ID       TIME
#> 1   1  0.7333070
#> 2   1 24.0668743
#> 3   1 47.3256351
#> 4   2  0.6980600
#> 5   2 13.0941023
#> 6   2 47.2417697
#> 7   3  0.7130828
#> 8   3 34.2428837
#> 9   3 47.5264165
#> 10  4  0.7381619
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @yipper8 See now, the code at the end.

Comment: @yipper8 Where does function `expand` come from?

Comment: @yipper8 SO, if I understand correctly, you have 34 id's?

Comment: @yipper8 I think I've got it, this time. See the edit.

Comment: @yipper8 Yes, I understand that. The code above will generate 3 pseudo-random numbers per ID, irrespective of the other columns. Can you edit the question with a data example in `dput` format? If you can, post the output of `dput(df1)` in the question.

Comment: @yipper8 It's not difficult to format on this site. Run `dput(df1)` in your R session and [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75946838/edit) pasting the output of `dput(df)`. To format this output as code, put three backticks before and after the posted code. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `runif` is vectorized. Simply do:

```
runif(34 * 3,  c(0.5, 12, 47),c(1, 48, 49))
```

The head of this vector is:

```
[1]  0.9758125 12.1717997 48.5416910  0.5152847 21.6146284 47.9904000
```